# Datepicker can't work with Sammy.js

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, sammy.js

i've been using datepicker in many of my projects, but this one project, i've got a problem with it.

the prev/next buttons don't act like it suppose to do. when i clicked it, it redirects to the default page. for example, here is the url where i implemented datepicker

```
$('input#_date').datepicker();

project.dev/index.html?q=123a21#/home
```

then, when i click prev/next button, it redirects me to default page which is

```
project.dev/
```

i have no idea why this one acts like this. has anyone any idea on how to fix this?

### EDITED:

i found out source of the problem but still can't figure out a way to solve it.

everytime i clicked next/prev button on datepicker, it always redirects to default router which is `$.sammy.get('')`. i found out that prev/next button on datepicker is actually an `<a>` tag without `href` attribute.

Comment: Do you have any custom behaviour for links in general? Got any console errors (F12 -> Console)?

Comment: @Ravenous no, i don't. console shows no error

Comment: Next / Prev are supposed to represent navigation for views, right? Be it days, months, years, decades etc. If that so, they may be wrapped as links, but they dont have to include a href as their default behaviour is meant to be prevents and they are supposed to act like controls for the library. Try doing this yourself and programatically change their behaviour using Datepicker's built-in methods, this will help you track the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve it eventhough (i still have no idea why it happens) by preventing the default event.

```
$('input#_date).datepicker({
     //options
}).focus(function() {
     $('.ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
     });
});
```